# Relative Extrema of $f(x,y) = 3x^2-2xy+y^2-8y$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do I find the relative extrema of such a function:
$f(x,y) = 3x^2-2xy+y^2-8y$

I have calculated:

$f_x = 6x-2y$  and
$f_y = 2y-2x-8$

How do I proceed from here?

NB. My challenge is on finding the Critical points.

Comment: Set what you calculated to zero and then solve the system for $x,y$. Also, if you have some domain in mind you will need to check the boundary directly.

Comment: Note that $f_x$ should be $6x-2y$

Answer (score 0):

You currently have $Df(x, y) = (6x - 2y, 2y - 2x - 8)$. Critical points are then solutions to the set $\begin{cases}9x -2y &= 0 \\ 2y - 2x - 8 &= 0 \end{cases}$. To then classify those critical points as minima or maxima, find the Hessian and see if it is positive or negative semi-definite.

Comment: OP made a slight mistake: $9x - 2y$ should be $6x - 2y$.

Answer (score 0):

The calculus approach would be to set the partial derivatives equal to zero.  There will be one critical point.  Then you would do a second derivative test to see whether this is a maximum an minimum or a saddle point.

The Linear algebra approach would be to see this a quadratic form.

$\pmatrix{x&y&1} \pmatrix{3&1&0\\1&1&4\\0&4&0} \pmatrix{x\\y\\1} = z$

And we can diagonalize the matrix which will point us to the minimum.